# How to take an arithmetic average over common variable, rather than whole data?

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a data frame which is daily data for stock prices, however, I have also a variable that indicates the week of year (1,2,3,4,...,51,52) this is repeated for 22 companies. I would like to create a new variable that takes an average of the daily prices but only across each week.

[image]

The above equation has d = day and t = week. My challenge is taking this average of days across each week. Therefore, I should have 52 values per stock that I observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ave()`.

```
dat <- transform(dat, avg_week_price=ave(price, week, company))
head(dat, 9)
#   week company wday    price avg_week_price
# 1    1       1    a 16.16528       15.47573
# 2    2       1    a 18.69307       15.13812
# 3    3       1    a 11.01956       12.99854
# 4    1       2    a 15.92029       14.56268
# 5    2       2    a 12.26731       13.64916
# 6    3       2    a 17.40726       17.27226
# 7    1       3    a 11.83037       13.02894
# 8    2       3    a 13.09144       12.95284
# 9    3       3    a 12.08950       15.81040
```

---

*Data:*

```
setseed(42)
dat <- expand.grid(week=1:3, company=1:5, wday=letters[1:7])
dat$price <- runif(nrow(dat), 10, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(week, company) %>%
    mutate(avg_week_price = mean(price))
```